# PHP: active Users

Tags: php, authentication

I just faced a problem. I am currently working on a project for school and I want to have all active users in the Sidebar (similar to a chat, but it's not).

First I thought of this (Pseudocode):

```
<?php
    ...
    class user {
        //Some instance vars.

        public function __construct(){
            //Write username in a textfile/database
        }
        public function logout {
            //Delete username from textfile/database
        }
    }
    ...
?>
```

The problems are:

1) The user-object is stored in the `$_SESSION[]` Array. So I can't use the magic method `__destruct()`. That's why I made the `logout()` Method. (Problem solved ^^)

2) If we assume that the user is logged in on 2 devices (eg. Laptop, Smartphone) with the same ID and he quits the session on one device, the other device will also be removed.

3) The user probably doesn't want to press the logout but and just closes the browser window. How do I know, that he logged out / quit the session.

I know, that PHP is not the best programming language for this kind of task, but I really want to do this project in PHP. I am really sorry, if this question has already been asked, but I carefully searched through all related questions and all of them differ (more or less) from mine.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, you can always check some pro code in the frameworks. The session in Symfony is in the HTTPFoundation component. http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html You can use a specific component if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a much better approach (and the one that's usually employed) is to have a table that contains two columns. The user id and the last time that the user was active on the site.

You'd keep this table up to date at login and potentially each time a user loads a page or performs some significant action on the site.

To show who's online you then query this table for any users that have been active in the last N seconds/minutes.

You may optionally wish to add a "cleanup" job that removes users from the table where their last activity was more than (something >N) seconds/minutes ago to keep that table from becoming too large.